# O que é Prisma?

Tags: prisma

Que raio de Prisma é essa? É de comer? Ou de programar? Nunca ouvi falar. Tag: [prisma](/questions/tagged/prisma)

Não quero saber tudo, mas uma informação básica sobre o que é isso.

Comment: Acho que é isso: http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/

Comment: Link interessante: https://linguagemprismablog.wordpress.com/

Comment: Com certeza não é algo popular ou deve ter algum erro nessa tag, pois não encontrei no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prisma

Comment: Prisma: Seu Primeiro Grande Carro!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prisma é uma linguagem de programação baseada em Lua e também um interpretador para esta linguagem. É bom salientar que a linguagem está em fase inicial e não encontrei informações relevantes sobre a quantas anda o desenvolvimento atualmente.

A linguagem conta com uma biblioteca gráfica nativa (chamada IG) com versões para Windows e Linux. Esta biblioteca gráfica tem a mesma licença de uso da GTK. A licença de uso do interpretador é a mesma licença de uso de Lua.

Segundo o [site oficial](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz) a linguagem possui uma versão com *statements* em português e outra em inglês.

Ainda com base no site oficial, algumas características da linguagem são (destaque e itálico por mim):

- Interpretada em [*bytecodes*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode);
- Tipagem dinâmica;
- Simplicidade de tipos;
- Portabilidade. O programa feito em Prisma não terá dificuldades em rodar nos mais populares sistemas operacionais;
- Própria para *script* (se preferir) ou usando o ***prisma compiler*** para "esconder o código";
- Muito rápida;
- Muito leve, não consome muitos recursos da máquina;
- Possui poderosos recursos para manipulação de dados: as tabelas;
- Recursos indiretos para aplicar a orientação a objetos: classes;
- Fácil de ser aprendida.

Comment: A alfinetada que eu vou dar aqui é pro autor da linguagem, não para o da resposta, ok? (btw +1). O que torna um programa rápido e leve ou não é uma combinação do que ele tem que fazer, o ambiente em que roda e principalmente a habilidade do programador.

Comment: E para quem não sabe o que é Bytecode, recomendo que dê uma lida na Wiki da tag: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/bytecode/info (é um começo apenas).

Answer (score 6):

O que é Prisma?  https://linguagemprismablog.wordpress.com/about/

Prisma é um interpretador para a linguagem de programação que leva o mesmo nome.

Ela possui diversas características, tais como:

- interpretada em byte codes;
- tipagem dinâmica;
- simplicidade de tipos;
- portabilidade, o programa feito em Prisma não terá dificuldades em rodar nos mais populares sistemas operacionais;
- própria para script (se preferir) ou usando o prisma compiler para esconder o código;
- muito rápida;
- muito leve, não consome muitos recursos da máquina;
- possui poderosos recursos para manipulação de dados: as Tabelas;
- recursos indiretos para aplicar a orientação a objetos: classes;
- fácil de ser aprendida;

Comment: Essas características são verdades, ou é meramente opinião do autor da linguagem? Creio que coisas como "muito rápida" e "muito leve" deva ser algo bem relativo, não? Acho que sua resposta ainda pode ser aprimorada ;)

Comment: Eu copiei a informação dada pelo autor mas já faço uso em ambiente de produção há pelo menos um ano e posso afirmar com certeza que é bem leve, realmente consome poucos recursos comparada a um java da vida!

Comment: Eu só disse que a resposta pode ser aprimorada, deixando claro que essas características são opiniões do autor da linguagem ;) ... De resto a resposta esta boa